# How to access Mysql database built on .Net Identity 2 in ASP.Net Core 2.1

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I was tasked with building a new website from scratch using ASP.NET Core 2.1, and I need to keep existing users that are stored on a MySql Database. The old website was built on ASP.Net MVC 5, with Identity 2/OWIN handling all of the user management.

At a high level, how would I go about accessing these existing users on ASP.NET Core 2.1? Is this something I can just connect to since both frameworks utilize Identity? Or do I need to utilize a new database context? (dotnet ef migrations, etc)